# Restore of copy_only backup of encrypted database made without FORMAT but with INIT fails

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, sql-server-2019

I have a task of making periodical copy of the database, twice a day, and I should not break any backup chain niether accumulate these temporary backups. So I tried to take a `copy_only` backup with `init` in order to overwrite the single backup file.

**My database in encrypted by using TDE**.

I use `backup compression` at the server level, "backup compression default" is 1 in my sys.configurations. I don't use explicit `with compression` option in my command.

Here my full @@version:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU8) (KB4577194) - 15.0.4073.23 (X64)
> Sep 23 2020 16:03:08    Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
> Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0
>  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

My problem is this error below:

> Msg 3241, Level 16, State 40, Line 8 The media family on device
> 'W:\SQL_backup\copy_only\billing_prod2_test.bak' is incorrectly
> formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family. Msg 3013, Level
> 16, State 1, Line 8 RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Here is the full code I executed:

```
backup database billing_prod2
to disk = 'W:\SQL_backup\copy_only\billing_prod2_test.bak'
with init, copy_only--, format;
go

restore database billing_1
from disk = 'W:\SQL_backup\copy_only\billing_prod2_test.bak'
with move 'billing_prod2' to 'E:\SQL_data\billing_1.mdf',
move 'billing_prod2_log' to 'E:\SQL_data\billing_1_log.ldf',
replace
```

The first time it executes without errors, the size of full backup is about 35Mb and it restores perfectly.

The second time the backup executes without error but strangely has a size of 260Mb. This is the size I see on the disk and the same size is written in the output of `restore headeronly` that still executes without errors. But when I do `restore database` the error mentioned above appears.

I tried to execute the same code using another db and another disk to save the backup but the result is always the same: the first time it works, the second time the file is overwritten but has different size that is not just a double size, it's almost 10 times of initial size. `restore headeronly` never fails and always reports only one file within the backup file but the size is multipticated and `restore database` fails.

[image: without format]

Only when I added `format` option the size of backup became normal and restore succeeded.

[image: with format]

My question is: why should I use format with my backup in this case to be able to restore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in SQL Server. We (@sepupic and I) had some discussions offline and managed to narrow down the circumstances: The error occurs when:

- You use TDE
- The backup is compressed
- You specify COPY_ONLY
- You specify INIT
- The backup file exists

Repro:

```
--The database has TDE
--Backupfile doesn't exist at this stage

BACKUP DATABASE db1Encrypted
TO DISK = 'R:\db1Encrypted.bak'
WITH INIT, COPY_ONLY, COMPRESSION, CHECKSUM

--backup file 660 kb

RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = 'R:\db1Encrypted.bak' WITH CHECKSUM
--OK


--Backupfile now exists, below causes unreadable backup

BACKUP DATABASE db1Encrypted
TO DISK = 'R:\db1Encrypted.bak'
WITH INIT, COPY_ONLY, COMPRESSION, CHECKSUM

--backup file 3890 kb

RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = 'R:\db1Encrypted.bak' WITH CHECKSUM
--Fails "The media family on device 'R:\db1Encrypted.bak' is incorrectly formed"
```